# Is it possible to use ECDH with AWS KMS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cryptography, amazon-kms, ecdh

a decision was made to use **AWS KMS** as a key storage and I have encountered a use case, when I need to have a shared secret with another entity by using **ECDH** ( Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman ). Are there any workarounds, where I can generate a shared secret without having the private key or maybe **AWS** has some function to do so.

Note: I am using **Python**